# How to dynamically reload a .css?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a website that I would like to present different styles for evaluation by having users click on a link(s) where an according proposed style gets loaded.  How can I dynamically reload .css files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you should be able to manipulate the css elements (such as `document.createElement("style");` and then filling it with what you need and appending it to the page.  Replacing that element will change the css that the page is styled with.  However, if you are trying to switch between linked .css files, it may not work dynamically because it could require a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadjscssfile(filename) {
            var fileref = document.createElement("link")
            fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
            fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
        }
        if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }    
</script>
```